# How to make power-law function linear?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a `y=1/x` curve. As X approaches one, Y goes torwards zero. This is what I want, but it nears zero to fast. Currently, it goes 
1 0.5 0.25 ...

I would much rather like it to be linear like this: 
1 0.9 0.8 0.7

Here is how the value is calculated, it's probably possible to simplify it aswell.

```
var splashopacity = ((1/(foo/bar))/bar);
```

Comment: Well `(1/(foo/bar))/bar` is `1/foo` ...

Comment: How is the jQuery library related to this question?

Comment: @Pointy, darn! back to drawingboard

Comment: @JanDvorak, not sure whar math capabillities are included in jquery

Comment: @KristofferNolgren pretty much none at all, I'm afraid

Comment: Ha well the basic answer is that if `1/foo` converges to zero too fast, that basically means that `foo` is getting big too fast. You can introduce a linear "stretch" by just dividing `foo` by some constant (which may be what you were trying to do in the formula you posted). Another way to write that is to use a numerator bigger than 1.

Comment: "I have a `y = 1/x` curve.  As X approaches one, Y goes towards zero."  Wat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are searching the right ease function for your application.
There are lots of ease function, it would be difficult to say the one that
fits your need.
here you have a graphical view of some functions : http://easings.net/en
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in your case (y=1/x), as x approaches 1, y approaches 1 as well
maybe you need:

y=1-x   (assuming x approaches to 1 from the left)

or

y=1-1/x  (assuming x approaches to 1 from the right)